# Using Kendo pie charts, is it possible to set the opacity background of the labels?

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I am trying to remove the background box of inner labels. Playing around with the debugger, I can set the opacity to 0 and it looks great, but I cannot find an option to set this.[image: Pie Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `background: "transparent"` on the labels object e.g.:

```
            seriesDefaults: {
                labels: {
                    template: "#= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage)#",
                    position: "center",
                    visible: true,
                    background: "transparent"
                }
            },
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/EgocI)**

Comment: This very well may be the correct answer but I'm not sure what setting the background to transparent is actually doing.  If I removed that from your demo, it doesn't seem to make a difference in how the labels look.

Comment: @RickS  that's because it's most likely the default, and you seem to be overriding it, maybe in your css?  if you change the background to white you'll see that it affects the demo.